# Database relations in Laravel Module

Tags: laravel

I've a problem in using database relationships together with Laravel module.
for example:

1. I've User module & Profile Module
2. I've One-to-One relation between user & profile (in 2 separated modules)
3. I need to get profile information when I have user data (example: `$user->profile`)

But I think because of creating relation between two modules, I cannot access to this relation.

My received error:
**"message": "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'user.profiles' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `profiles` where `profiles`.`user_id` = 2 and `profiles`.`user_id` is not null limit 1)",
"exception": "Illuminate\Database\QueryException",**

User Module/Entities/User.php

```
<?php

namespace Modules\User\Entities;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Modules\VofourCourse\Entities\Profile;


class User extends Authenticatable 
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $connection = 'user';

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    
    
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
}
```

Profile Module/Entities/Profile.php

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Profile\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Modules\User\Entities\User;
use RichanFongdasen\EloquentBlameable\BlameableTrait;

class Profile extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes, BlameableTrait;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Profile Module/Controller/ProfileController.php

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Profiole\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;


class ProfileController extends Controller
{

    public function showProfile()
    {
        $user = auth('api')->user();
        return $user->profile;
    }

}
```

Profile migration

```
 Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('whatsapp_mobile', 15)->unique();
            $table->string('phone', 15)->unique();
            $table->string('national_code', 10)->nullable();
            $table->string('postal_code', 10)->nullable();
            $table->text('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('job_title')->nullable();
            $table->foreignId('city_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('father_name')->nullable();
            $table->enum('marital_status', ['married', 'single', 'widow', 'divorced', 'unknown'])->default('married');
        });
```

User migration

````
Schema::connection(config('modules.connections.user_database'))->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('firstname')->nullable();
            $table->string('lastname')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('vofour_id' , 10)->nullable();
            $table->string('username', 20)->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->date('birth_date')->nullable();
            $table->enum('gender', ['male', 'female'])->nullable();
            $table->string('mobile', 15)->unique();
            $table->enum('status', ['active', 'inactive'])->default('active');
            $table->rememberToken();
        });```
thanks a lot for your helps & guidance
````

Comment: Could you please add your database migration files for user and profile? The error message says that there are no `profiles` table in your database.

Comment: Thanks, I've placed my migrations (user & profile) for more details..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a typing error in your relationship. The error states there should be a relation `profiles` where as from your code there's a profile.

```
 public function profile()
 {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
 }
```

What you can do is return `user->with('profile')` which will return the user with it's relational details. I.e.

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Profiole\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;


class ProfileController extends Controller
{

    public function showProfile()
    {
        $user = auth('api')->user();
        return $user->with('profile');
    }

}
```

Also update your profiles migration line where `user_id` is written from:
    `$table->foreignId('user_id')->onDelete('cascade');` to     `$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');`.

This will link up the `user_id` as a foreign key to `users` table id. and return the correct collection of users with their profiles.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention.. But if I change my codes & implement your alternative code, I receive an another error as below..

**"message": "Property [id] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.",**

Comment: updated the answer. Also update your profiles migration line where `user_id` is written from:    ` $table->foreignId('user_id')->onDelete('cascade');` to     `$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');.`

This will link up the `user_id` as a foreign key to users table id. and return the correct collection of users with their profiles.

Comment: the `users` inside `constrained` is the table name for your users table.

Comment: Thanks for your time & attention.. Finally, I could resolve this problem only with adding foreign_key and local_key to the relation in User entity..

Comment: If the answer helped you resolving the issue. Please accept it for others as well.

Comment: yes, sure.. thanks a lot dear sir